# Order by username with specific name first (php)

Tags: php

I been looking but I cant find any way to do this. I'm trying to order sql result by username but with specific name first, i dont knwo if this is possible, here is the code:

```
SELECT A.user_id, A.username, B.user_colour FROM likes AS A, users AS B
            WHERE sta_id=$sta_id AND A.user_id = B.user_id 
          ORDER BY username ASC;
```

the specific name that i want to show first let call it "testing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a case statement into the `ORDER BY` which effectively assigns a lower value to the specific name than everything else.  That is then followed by a regular `username` order for the rest to be alphabetical ASC

```
SELECT A.user_id, A.username, B.user_colour FROM likes AS A, users AS B
WHERE sta_id=$sta_id AND A.user_id = B.user_id 
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN A.username = 'some specific name' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
 username ASC;
```

Comment: You're combining a `DESC` sort (1 on top of 0) with an `ASC` sort - something specifically advised against in the manual ;)

Comment: Ah, you sniped my comment :D Nice one.

Comment: thanks a lot but i got an error on it : Column 'username' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: @user1133401 Should be `A.username`. Fixed above.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY (username='testing') DESC,username ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY IF(`username`='testing',0,1) ASC, `username` ASC
```

Should do it nicely.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm too lazy to RTFM on this. Does using the `IF` in your `ORDER BY` prevent MySQL from using an index to sort?

Comment: Ah... I honestly don't know. You'd have to run `EXPLAIN` on it to find out.

Comment: @rdlowrey, I'm afraid, even `='testing'` may prevent mysql from using an index to sort.